# MySQL drop down list

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question, I am wondering if it is possible to show a drop-down list with MySQL which will include the categorie.

For example:

> -- fuits --
>   Apple
>   Bananas
>   Pears
>   -- cheese --
>   Gouda
>   Mozzarella
>   ...

I know how to do the query to show the category together with the name (as below):

> Fruit - Apple
>   Fruit - Bananas
>   Fruit - Pears
>   Cheese - Gouda
>   Cheese - Mozzarella

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Where or how are you performing this query? Just with MySQL itself? Within a program?

Comment: show the drop down where?

Comment: Sorry, to show in a website with php. 

trying to edit my question, bu I don't see the option to edit.

Comment: Yes. Perfectly possible. Next.

Comment: Yes. You have to build it. Take the output like in your second yellow box and write a loop in PHP to build the output you want in HTML.

Comment: The edit button is right below the tags.

Comment: Ok I see now how to do it. Thank you :)